# Script to Quickly Determine What Source Code Causes Unnecessary .so's to link

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, ldd, build-dependencies

*Context:* I have a program which transfers an executable over a network. This executable is way too large, so I ran `ldd -u bigFoo.so` on its associated shared object. This revealed that I had a large number of unused shared object files which were occupying over a gig.

*Question:* Given a piece of C++ source code `foo.cc` which is compiled and linked into `bigFoo.so`, and `unused.so` (revealed by `ldd -u`) which is linked into `bigFoo.so`, is there a script or sequence of shell commands which can quickly determine what calls in `foo.cc` cause linkage of `unused.so`?

Comment: But... But... linked files __aren't__ part of a program executable... they're... _linked_ in at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recompile after adding the option `-Wl,-M` to your `CXXFLAGS`.  Search for '**Archive member included...**', The following lines will show what libraries where included in the file, and what functions requested them.

An example:

```
gcc -std=gnu99  -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wunused -Wl,-M -c showmmap.c -o showmmap.o
gcc -std=gnu99  -O0 -Wall -Wextra -Wunused -Wl,-M    showmmap.o -o showmmap
Archive member included to satisfy reference by file (symbol)

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(elf-init.oS)
                              /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o (__libc_csu_init)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc_nonshared.a(fstat.oS)
                              showmmap.o (fstat)

Discarded input sections
--------8<--snip--->8-----
```

I had to dig around in my archives to find something that pulled in other libraries.  In this example, you can see that **__libc_csu_init** and **fstat** are functions which requested other archive members to be included.

The output of the `-Wl,-M` option is rather... voluminous, be sure to pipe the output to a file or through `less`

What I've shown here is but a teeny snippet from the very head of the output.  Your output should be longer, considering you likely have many library routines included.